# How to access executable for ComposableNodeContainer for gdb debugging?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a .py launch file that defines two composable node descriptions: `desc1` and `desc2`, each of which describe two nodes that are already built and registered as

```
rclcpp_components_register_node(node1
  PLUGIN "node1NS::node1node"
  EXECUTABLE node1_node
)
```

and

```
rclcpp_components_register_node(node2
  PLUGIN "node2NS::node2node"
  EXECUTABLE node2_node
)
```

in their respective CMakeLists.txt files

The .py launch file then uses the two descriptions to create a ComposableNodeContainer like so:

```
container = ComposableNodeContainer(
    name="NodeContainer",
    namespace="",
    package="rclcpp_components",
    executable=LaunchConfiguration("container_executable"),
    prefix="gdbserver 127.0.0.1:3050",
    composable_node_descriptions=[
        desc1,
        desc2,
    ],
    output="screen",
)
```

I added `prefix` so that I can hook a dubugging instance to this container in the launchfile (which is nested within 4 other levels of launch-files)

Now I wish to create a `launch.json` in VSCode to debug, so I wrote this configuration:

```
  {
    "name": "NodeDebug",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "miDebuggerServerAddress": "127.0.0.1:3050",
    "program": <executable-here>,
    "preLaunchTask": "launch_nodes",
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
      {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
        "ignoreFailures": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

I know what to add to `program:` if I were debugging a single node (ie. `node1_node` and `node2_node`). However, since the executable for this container is built on runtime, how I do access it? Is there any other way to debug a ComposableNodeContainer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407143/how-to-access-executable-for-composablenodecontainer-for-gdb-debugging?/) by [jd2548](https://answers.ros.org/users/119329/jd2548/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is possible, however the tricky part is selecting the correct process when you are attaching your debugger.

As an example, I can show you how I set a breakpoint in the talker node of the [composition demo](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/rolling/composition).

1. Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/ms-iot/vscode-ros/blob/master/doc/debug-support.md). You should simply add the following to your `launch.json`

   {
   "configurations": [
   {
   "name": "ROS: Attach",
   "type": "ros",
   "request": "attach"
   }
   ]
   }
2. Launch your component container, in this case `ros2 launch composition ./composition_demo.launch.py`
3. Launch the `ROS: Attach` debug target in vscode. Pick `c++`; when you get the drop down menu to choose a process, look for the one running the **component container**, not the launch file. As illustrated in the screenshot below.  You might get a prompt asking for admin priveleges in the console during this process.

[image: debug component container]

Finally, place a breakpoint somewhere to stop the program

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) with karma: 131 on 2022-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0